# Custom font not loaded in iOS 13 beta

Tags: ios, fonts

The font is added in the bundle and is declared in info.plist.
It works in iOS 12, but no longer in iOS 13 beta.
Any idea ?

[Update]
It seems that this is a particular issue for the font I use: DINNeuzeitGrotesk-BoldCond-Regular.ttf.
I converted to otf and problem solved.

Comment: Are the converted back to system one? or any inconsistency alert while opening the storyboard?

Comment: It converted back to system font at runtime, but in storyboard, it still left the font name in the field, but it doesn't recognise the font.

Comment: Yes I've also faces same issue, and couldn't found any solution, but whenever the alert comes on opening the storyboard, I quit Xcode instead accepting the changes Xcode wanted to made. So after re launching the Xcode I found the correct fonts.